# What permissions should I choose for github fine-grained personal tokens?

Tags: git, github

I got `fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Username/X.git/'` after inputting the correct username and password.

I read this https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-12-git-password-authentication-is-shutting-down/ and think I should create a personal token.

I created a fine-grained personal access token but when I tried to `git push -u origin main` I got `The requested URL returned error: 403`.

When I created my fine-grained personal access token I didnt select any user permissions or repository permissions because I dont know what any of them means. Did this cause the problem? what permissons should I choose?

[image]

There are so many permissions and it looks so confusing.

Comment: In my experience you don't need a "fine-grained" PAT. Just make a PAT and be done with it.

Comment: I agree - the number of permissions is overwhelming. I'm sure they all have their uses, but I think 99% of the time we just want to pull and/or push. Setting that up should be dead simple. 'Contents' should at least appear near the top, and not hidden in a long list of things I'll probably never need.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The permission for pushing seems to be *Contents*.

The alternatives to a fine-grained token are:

1. Use a classic token. *Fine-grained tokens are still in Beta*
2. Use Github cli and [gh auth login](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) with its web browser authentication
   (the browser is launched from the console).
   *This approach doesn't suffer from the problem of expired tokens, but please be aware that for some setups [gh auth login writes oauth_token to .config/gh/hosts.yaml even without passing --insecure-storage](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/7757#issuecomment-1653960716)*

Comment: Note that the GitHub-CLI stored the token in _plaintext_ before [version 2.24.0 (2023-03-08)](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.24.0). And it still has a [fallback to store it as plaintext (if no system keyring/keychain/wallet, etc.) is found](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/7757#issuecomment-1653960716)

Comment: @Dominik so basically this whole measure to improve security might just result in the equivalent of a plaintext password being stored on my system if I don't use a password manager?

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund Yes, at least that's what the [`gh auth login --help` still shows](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/1953a9e0f7262ea0643e10f52da873d9e439cd4f/pkg/cmd/auth/login/login.go#L62-L64):
"If a credential store is not found or there is an issue using it gh will fallback to writing the token to a plain text file. See `gh auth status` for its stored location."

Comment: @tymtam Can you add a warning to your answer? Or would it be ok for you when I add it?